# PIC programming problem: [ Pgm ] at 0x0, expected 0x00003180, got 0x00003fff

Tags: pic, mplabx, pickit

Got a problem when trying to program a PIC12F1840 with PicKit 4 in MPLAB X IDE v6.05.

When I program it I get the error:

```
[ Pgm ] at 0x0, expected 0x00003180, got 0x00003fff
```

Does somebody know how I can solve this? I found a similar question, but it did not answer my problem.

---

**EDIT**

I actually got it to work by changing the memory range for the PicKit 4, but I have to program the PIC with a program written in BASIC with PICBASIC PRO compiler. Here I use MPLAB X IDE v5.35 and get the error:

```
Verify failed.
[ Pgm ] at 0x0, expected 0x0000294c, got 0x00003fff
```

But I cannot get it to work the same way I did before because the expected address is not the same. I think at least.

The schematic of the connections is seen here. I have soldered headers from USB to the PicKit 4. Just want to point out that I have not created this print by myself, but have made this schematic out of gerber files from the original.

[image]

Also tried it with another print, but I get the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try another one. This error typically indicates faulty flash memory in the MCU.

Comment: Can you show us a schematic of your connections?

Comment: In what way did you change the memory range? -- Since the error message comes in the verification phase, how did the programming phase run?

Comment: I changed the memory range from 0-fff to 200-2ff. I guess the programming phase is fine. Before verify failed, it says: 
The following memory area(s) will be programmed:
program memory: start address = 0x200, end address = 0x2ff
configuration memory
EEData memory
User Id Memory

But after the verify failed it says: Programming did not complete.