# Problems programming PIC16F15213 with PICkit4

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I'm having problems programming my PIC16F15213. I am trying to program it with the PICkit4 and it gives me this error:

```
[ Pgm ] at 0x0, expected 0x00002825, got 0x00000000. Programming did not complete.
```

I have already tried to modify the programming speed, the power supply etc., but it still gives me this error.

I am using MPLABXIDE 6.00 - PIC16F1xxxx_DFP v1.9.163 - XC8 v2.40 compiler.

Comment: Some of the comments on [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/662766/pic-programming-problem-pgm-at-0x0-expected-0x00003180-got-0x00003fff) might be helpful.

Comment: do you have the right part selected in your project?